# Open a menu list from a button inside an iframe

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, css, webforms

I have an asp:Button which I want to open a menu, I would like to load a custom menu depending on the pageID in a box to the left of the menu button. I have been testing this using a jQuery dialog so far which works for now but doesnt have the required functionality.

I want to create the menu dynamically so what would be useful is an iframe which loads the menu page in a box, to the left of the button.

This is what it should look like:
[image]

This is the code that I use to open the menu at the moment in a dialog, if it can be changed somehow to just load an iframe next to that button that would be great:

```
    var $dial2 = ""
    function openmenu(title, width, height, menuID) {
        $dial2 = $('<div></div>')
                       .html('<iframe id="dial1" style="border: 0px; " src=/CustomControls/PageSubMenu.aspx?&menuID="' + menuID + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>')
                       .dialog({
                           autoOpen: false,
                           modal: true,
                           height: height,
                           width: width,
                           title: title
                       });
        $dial2.dialog('open');
    }
```

Comment: I can not understand what you try to do and where you stack. For me is better to have a simple approach that works and is robust, then maybe you can use some ajax to dynamic change some parts of your page...

Comment: In theory it is simple, it is just an iframe contained in something joined to the side of a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I achieved this using the dialog shown above, but used the position property to join it to the edge of my button. I added a button inside the dialog to close it and also added a close event to any button that is shown within the menu.

```
function openmenu(width, height, menuID) {
    if ($dial2 == "") {
        $dial2 = $('<div></div>')
                       .html('<iframe id="dial2" style="border: 0px; " src=/CustomControls/PageSubMenu.aspx?&menuID="' + menuID + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>')
                       .dialog({
                           autoOpen: false,
                           modal: false,
                           height: height,
                           width: width,
                           title: 'Menu',
                           draggable: false,
                           resizable: false,
                           position: {
                               my: 'top',
                               at: 'left-207',
                               of: $('#btnMenu')
                           },
                           dialogClass: "testdia"
                       });
        $dial2.dialog('open');

    }
    else {
        closemenu();
    }
    }
```